# Flutter bloc yield state is not received in listener

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, bloc

I add a event to bloc immediately after pop a CupertinoModalPopup. But yield a state and not received in bloc listener. The code is like below.There are more states and events, and it's all working, except this state is not received. I don't know why, maybe it's because I add the event after the showCupertinoModalPopup was pop. I am not sure. I didn't paste the whole codes here, I only kept the relevant code. I did set the breakpoint on `yield ProfileUploadAvatarSucceed(user)`, and it stops here.

```
BlocBuilder<ProfileBloc, ProfileState>(
  builder: (context, state) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () async {
        final file = await showCupertinoModalPopup(
            context: context,
            builder: (popupContent) {
              return CupertinoActionSheet(
                actions: [
                  CupertinoActionSheetAction(
                    child: Text('Photo Library'),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      final imageFile = await _picker.getImage(
                          source: ImageSource.gallery,
                          imageQuality: 70,
                          maxWidth: 480);
                      if (imageFile != null) {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop(imageFile);
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              );
            });
        BlocProvider.of<ProfileBloc>(context).add(UploadAvatarEvent(file));
    };
  },
  listener: (_, state) {
    if (state is ProfileLoadingState) {
      BotToast.showLoading();
    } else if (state is ProfileUploadAvatarSucceed) {
      BotToast.closeAllLoading();
      BotToast.showText(text: 'Avatar updated');
    }
  }
);
```

ProfileBloc.dart

```
@override
Stream<ProfileState> mapEventToState(
  ProfileEvent event,
) async* {
  if (event is UploadAvatarEvent) {
    yield ProfileLoadingState();
    await _apiProvider.updateUser(currentUser.id, payload);
    final user = await _apiProvider.getUser(currentUser.id);
    yield ProfileUploadAvatarSucceed(user);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are both `ProfileLoadingState` and `ProfileUploadAvatarSucceed` not received? Or only one of them?

Comment: @KirillBubochkin Yes, both states not received.

Comment: Do you receive any errors in the console?

Comment: @KirillBubochkin No error.

Comment: Wait, are you sure you've pasted the correct code? `BlocBuilder` doesn't have `listener` parameter.